# send multiple values from jsp to controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am making a spring application where i have a jsp page that has got tables that prints data of object Car like carid, name etc.
Now i have added the feature to edit and delete them, but i have a situation where i need to book them.
I have a row that has car details and a date picker with a book button. My question is- 
How can i pass carid with the date selected to a specific controller, though i have done edit and delete function using carid, but now that a separate date has been added, i am confused how do i send the id with date to the controller.

Here is my jsp code, please help. thanks

```
<c:if test="${!empty listOfAvailableCars}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">Id</th>
            <th width="120">Car Name</th>
            <th width="120">Car Model</th>
            <th width="120">Car Number</th>
            <th width="120">Car Type</th>
            <th width="120">AC/ NON AC</th>
            <th width="60">Booking Date</th>
        </tr>       
        <c:forEach items="${listOfAvailableCars}" var="availableCars">      
            <tr>
                <td>${availableCars.id}</td>
                <td>${availableCars.name}</td>
                <td>${availableCars.model}</td>
                <td>${availableCars.type}</td>
                <td>${availableCars.number}</td>
                <td>${availableCars.isAC}</td>
                <td><input type="datetime" value="bookingDate"/></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/bookCar/${availableCars.id}'/>">Book</a></td>   
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>    
    </table>    
</c:if>
```

Here is the controller -

@Controller

public class BookingController {

```
@Autowired
private CarService carService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/bookCar/{id}")
public String bookCar(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    carService.bookCar(id);
    return "userDashboard";

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a java controller class? Could you post that so we can help you? With Spring Rest, you will map endpoints (i.e. the `/bookCar/id` url route) to methods within the controller to pass them to the backend.

Comment: @zacran added cntroller !

Comment: @zacran i am mostly concerned about passing the date which isnt the part of availableCar obj here with availableCar.id , i can send just the id , that works fine, how do i send both, using a form ? what do you say

Comment: Once you start wanting to pass multiple fields to the backend, you might want to consider using a POST operation instead of a GET; in Spring this is `@PostMapping`. This lets you send the whole `availableCars` object to the controller. You could also keep it as a GET and use multiple `@PathVariables` like `bookCar/{id}/{date}`

Comment: @zacran and how do i send the date from jsp ? in the url ?

Comment: Get the value from the datetime input and add it to the url. Something like this `<c:url value='/bookCar/${availableCars.id}/{bookingDate}'/>`.

Comment: @zacran ok cool let me try that !